# JSON result get country from address_components

Tags: javascript, json, html

Hi new to JSON and I was wondering if I can call the "country" from this API's JSON result: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places

I tried to use a loop that gets the last part of the JSON result address_components but I realized that the location of the "country" varies from the user's input

To elaborate:
Scenario 1:
USER's INPUT:
736 Lockhart Court, Harristown QLD 4350, Australia

Result:
Australia //this is correct

Scenario 2:
USER's INPUT:
Langley Air Force Base, Hampton, VA, United States

Result:
Virginia //not correct

My current code gets the last index of the array address_components and I am wondering if I can just do something like this ***data.results[0].address_components[country].long_name;***, but I just don't know the proper way.

Code:

```
<html>  
<head></head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#btn1 ").click(function() {
       var address=encodeURI($('#userInput').val());
       var url='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+address+'&sensor=true';
       $.getJSON(url, function(data){
          for(var row=0; row<data.results.length;row++){
             document.getElementById('res').value = (data.results[row].address_components[data.results[row].address_components.length-2].long_name);
          }       
     });
   });
});
</script>         
<body>

<input type="text" id="res">    
<input type="text" name="userInput" id="userInput" />

  <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Load Data" />
</body>
</html>
```

How can I get a specific(country,street number etc) element without relying on the address_components index?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in your case you will have to manually iterate the array and check that the `types` array contains `'country'`. You can use [array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) for this.

```
for(var row=0; row<data.results.length;row++){
    var item = data.results[row];
    for( var i = 0; i< item.address_components.length; i++) {
         var component = item.address_components[i];
         if( component.types.indexOf('country') != -1) {
             document.getElementById('res').value = component.long_name;
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: Need to use 'indexOf' not 'indexof' (case sensitive)

Answer (score 1):

A more updated answer using ES6

```
data.results[0].address_components.forEach(_item => {
  if (_item.types.indexOf('country') !== -1) {
     document.getElementById('res').value = _item.short_name;
  }
});
```